# official test suite for PL/I like for Cobol 85?

Tags: testing, standards, ansi, cobol85, pl-i

Could anybody point me to an official test suite for PL/I ?

as PL/I is an ANSI standard, I was hoping to find such a suite but I'm unsuccessful in my search until now.

Ideal would be to find a suite like the test suite for COBOL85 test suite produced by the National Computing Centre and available at http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/ctg/cobol_form.htm

Goal is to validate a PL/I compiler for x86 through formal testing.

Thanks in advance !

didier